# Double Counting Argument Regarding the Link Graph

Tags: combinatorics

The below question is self contained but just so I properly cite in what context the question arose, [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669885800238) is the paper I was reading when the question came up.

Suppose that a $k$-uniform hypergraph $\mathcal{F}$ on $N$ vertices is $r$-dense -- i.e. every $r$-set is contained in at least one $k$-edge) -- and suppose that
$$
|\mathcal{F}| \leq (1+\delta) \frac{\binom{N}{r}}{\binom{k}{r}}. 
$$
For each $r$ set $S$, let $d(S)$ be the number of edges in
$\mathcal{F}$ that contain $S$. By noting that every $r$-set $S$ is in $d(S)$
edges and each $k$-edge $F$ contains $\binom{k}{r}$ $r$-sets, we find that
$$
\sum_{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}} d(S) = |\mathcal{F}|\binom{k}{r} \leq (1+\delta)\binom{N}{r}.
$$
Since $\mathcal{F}$ is $r$-dense, every $r$-set is contained in at least one edge.
Thus
$$
\binom{N}{r} \leq \sum_{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}}d(S) \leq (1+\delta)\binom{N}{r}.
$$
Note further that we can split the above summation into
$$
\binom{N}{r} \leq \sum_{\substack{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}, \\ d(S) = 1}} d(S) + 
\sum_{\substack{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}, \\ d(S) \geq 2}} d(S)
\leq (1+\delta)\binom{N}{r}.
$$
I have been trying to use this to conclude (as they do in the paper) that
$$
\sum_{\substack{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}, \\ d(S) \geq 2}} d(S) \leq 2\delta\binom{N}{r}.
$$
However, I have not been able to prove this fact yet. Any suggestions as to a better way to think about this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an argument a friend of mine showed me:

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}} d(S) &= \sum_{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}} (d(S) - 1 + 1) \\
&= \binom{N}{r} + \sum_{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}} (d(S) - 1) \\
&= \binom{N}{r} + \sum_{\substack{S \in \binom{[N]}{r} \\ d(S) \geq 2}} d(S) - 1 \\
&\geq \binom{N}{r} + \sum_{\substack{S \in \binom{[N]}{r} \\ d(S) \geq 2}} \frac12 \cdot d(S).\\
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
\frac12 \sum_{\substack{S\in \binom{[N]}{r} \\ d(S) \geq 2}} d(S) \leq 
\sum_{S \in \binom{[N]}{r}} d(S) - \binom{N}{r} \leq (1+\delta)\binom{N}{r} - \binom{N}{r} = \delta\binom{N}{r}.
$$